# Specify entity class name in Symfony Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using YAML for configuring the Doctrine ORM mappings in Symfony 4. Is there any way to specify the class name of an entity manually in its config? It seems like the entity's class name is generated based on the name of the yml config file and there is no way to override it.

Say I have a mapping config called `Foo.orm.yml`. Doctrine is going to think that the actual name of the entity class is `Foo`. But what if I want the `Foo.orm.yml` file to map the table onto the class `Bar`? So I was thinking about something like the `class` option inside the config, but haven't found anything on the Internet.

```
#file Foo.orm.yml

Bar:
    class: Bar
    type: entity
    table: bar
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: NONE }
    fields:
        foo:
            type: string
        bar:
            type: boolean
```

XML mappings have the `name` option though: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/xml-mapping.html which doesn't work in YAML.

Answer (score 1):

Change **Bar** to **AppBundle\Entity\Bar**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Bar:
    type: entity
    table: bar
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: NONE }
    fields:
        foo:
            type: string
        bar:
            type: boolean
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Doctrine bundle ignores this top-level key.

Comment: This is how I use it in my projects (3.4)